Should I disclose my full academic history to graduate school after acceptance
I have been applying to various graduate school programs during my gap year since graduating with my undergraduate degree in 2023. Starting Jan-2024 I enrolled in a PhD program in my home country as a backup plan, and kept applying to various graduate schools.
In one such program, I failed to notify in the application form that I was currently enrolled in another program. I filled in the details before my enrollment in December 2023, and submitted my application around January 24, 2024, after an informal chat with a potential PI sometime around January 22, I had filled in all the necessary and standard details before meeting my potential PI to speed up the process as the deadline was approaching soon and I was not very careful in reviewing my application at the time of submission, this was also my first application post my spring-24 enrollment, so I filled the details in a bit of "auto-pilot" mode, after having filled a lot of applications where I was not enrolled in any other program. At the time of applying, though, my enrollment was very recent, there were no transcripts or much academic progress in the program, so this omission does not significantly alter my application at the time of submission.
Now I have received an offer letter from that graduate school, which I accepted. I noticed this issue when I had to upload some further documents post-acceptance for verification in the same application portal. Therefore, technically I did omit my enrollment from my application at the time of applying. I have now initiated the withdrawal process from my current enrollment, and I will soon officially terminate my current program.
I feel like I should notify the admissions office for the sake of complete transparency and to avoid future problems, but I am also worried my offer might get revoked. What should I do and how should I go about it?

Will the first enrolment be terminated before the second one starts?

Yes, it will be terminated

SHORT ANSWER
You will be fine as long as you end your first enrollment before the second one starts. You do not even need to mention your first enrollment, unless you absolutely wants to.
LONGER ANSWER
I do not know of any rule requesting to mention previous enrollments. Especially in the international context, application calendars are totally out of synchronization and enrolling into various programs is almost unavoidable. Transparency about such situation is (most often, not always) appreciated, but I think it would be frown upon if it was required, and it would be more important for the program which you leave (allowing them to reassign the resources assigned to you) than for the program which you join.
Good luck with your new program!

Thanks for the answer! I am only worried because the application explicitly wanted to know if I was enrolled in another graduate program. I entered "No" which was true at the time of entry but not at the time of submission, I should've been careful, but here I am now. I feel like this is important enough for me to report, although it had only been 2-3 weeks into my enrollment at the time of submission.
